# MediaWiki: What is the meaning of "attachedlocal" and "centralids"?

Tags: mediawiki-api

If I list information about user accounts via the MediaWiki API I receive the following information about each user:

```js
{
    "attachedlocal": {
        "local": ""
    },
    "centralids": {
        "local": <int>
    },
    "editcount": <int>,
    "groups": <strlist>,
    "implicitgroups": <strlist>,
    "name": <str>,
    "registration": <timestamp>,
    "rights": <strlist>,
    "userid": <int>
}
```

Though the API documentation does not explain these fields the meaning of most of the fields are pretty clear. What is unclear to me is the meaning of "`attachedlocal`" and "`centralids`". The "`local`" central ID seems to correlate with the user ID. Does anyone know why MediaWiki requires such data and what meaning that data has?

Answer (score 0):

See [central ID](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Central_ID) for `centralids`. `local` is always present and always the user ID, authentication extensions might add other fields. E.g. [GoogleLogin](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:GoogleLogin) will add the user's Google account ID.

`attachedlocal` is the result of `CentralIdLookup::isAttached()` (the empty string means true, which is a leftover from when the API was XML-based; use `formatversion=2` for a nicer syntax); ie. if your authentication extension enforces the same wiki username as the global account name it is based on, and a global user `Foo` and a wiki-user `Foo` both exist, this will tell whether they are the same user. Not many authentication extensions use this.